# redux devtools does not show state in extension devtools tab

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, redux

I'm writing a chrome extension using react and redux. The extension has it's own tabs in the chrome devtools. If I try to debug the react code, a new chrome devtools opens, where I can view the console, sources , etc.

I have the following in the store creation:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState, compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    global.devToolsExtension ? global.devToolsExtension() : f => f
))
```

The problem is, redux devtools appears, but no store is detected. I've also tried the instructions from [here](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#12-advanced-store-setup), but still to no effect.

I'd also like to mention that both, `global.devToolsExtension`, as well as `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` are `undefined`.

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get the state to display using [remote-redux-devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools). The trick was to right click `Open Remote Devtools`, and there, in the settings, mark to use local server.

In a separate tab, make sure you install `remotedev-server`, via npm or yarn. Example:

```
yarn add -D remotedev-server
```

and run the following:

```
var remotedev = require('remotedev-server');
remotedev({ hostname: 'localhost', port: 8000 });
```

Afte all this, the state should be visible in the redux devtools.

Comment: can u post any react native example which shows state in remote redux devtools please